# Fixed navigation bar doesnt work

Tags: html, css, navigation, fixed

I have a problem with my navigation bar. It is looking great now, but if I add a position:fixed to my css, it messes everything up. Also, if the bar can't fit horizontally on screen, the browser breaks it into two rows, so it fits, but I don't want that!
I added a bg height only so I can scroll and see if the navbar stays. 
What I want is a fixed navigation bar on top of the screen, not overlapping with future content, and filling the screen horizontally.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>NOT!fy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700|Roboto+Condensed:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- A roboto font stylesheetje a google fontsban -->
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav" align="center">
    <ul>
        <img src="img/notify_icon.png"/>
        <li><a href="#top">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divider">FEATURE SET</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divider4">WHO ARE WE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divider5">INDIEGOGO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#href">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#nav {
font-family: Century Gothic;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #353539;
height: 100px;
width: auto;
font-weight: bold;
border-width:0px;
opacity:0.95;
padding:0px;
}
#nav ul {
margin:0 auto;
width:auto;
height:100px;
}
#nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0px;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
border-right:1px solid #DDD;
height: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav ul li {
text-decoration: none;
color: #d2d2d2;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
margin-bottom: 90px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #d2d2d2;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 0px;
}


#nav ul li a:hover {
color: #ffd200;
}

#nav img{
 width:100px;
}

body
{
background-color:#c5c5c5;
height:1500px;
}
```

Here you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/DzLvT/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DzLvT/5/)

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#top">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divider">FEATURE SET</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divider4">WHO ARE WE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divider5">INDIEGOGO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#href">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


#nav{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:auto;
    background-color: #353539;
    height:50px;
}
#nav ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
}
#nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-right:1px solid #DDD;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:50px;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d2d2d2;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffd200;
}

body{
    background-color:#c5c5c5;
    height:1500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use css rules:

position:fixed; and top:0px;

on your menu tag

Answer (score 0):

u must give the #nav fixed with and a width with **% on the a tags** . They will be resized **within the width of their parent** if the space is too small they will go to a new line so **summ them to 97% total and leave 3% for margins and paddings**. instead of positioning the text with paddings u can use **Line-height for height** and **text-aling-center**

add to ur div somethink like **800/960px width remove the overflow**   and see the magic :D
just replace this in ur css:

```
#nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
width: 19%;
margin: 0px;
/* padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; REMOVE THE PADDING*/
border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 50px;  /*THE SAME AS HEIGHT BUT FOR text elements*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the #nav and iclude it on ul#nav, and add position fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/LZAhC/

```
  #nav ul {
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #353539;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width:0px;
  opacity:0.95;
  padding:0px;
position: fixed;
  }
  #nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-right:1px solid #DDD;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
  #nav ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d2d2d2;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d2d2d2;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  }


  #nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffd200;
  }

  #nav img{
width:100px;
  }

  body
  {
  background-color:#c5c5c5;
  height:1500px;
  }
```